# CSS rewrite but in the bottom of the code

Tags: css

I have some website for my customer, and I have access only to the footer...
wonder if I can put there a line code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.myserver.com/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

and with this file I will able to change the css, but the question is how can I rewrite to some class and the browser will ignore from the css that in the header...?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless the rules in the header use !important, your rules will override the ones in the header since the most recent rules override ones declared before them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add a link to the page footer, which isn't valid HTML but understood by any modern web browser.

To "overwrite" CSS-classes, just specify them again. If they don't get overwritten, read into CSS [specificity and inheritance](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/). But the browser won't ignore the first definition – you need to reset any unwanted rules.

Answer (score 1):

First make a list of all styles you want to override using various methods like FX 10 includes wonderful code inspector, firebug, webmaster toolbar.

Then declare style tag as following where you have access then you'll be able to override styles.

```
<style type="text/css">
 /* Styles go here*/
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place that link in the footer and then use `!important` on your css rules.

However please don't do this, it's not recommended and you could be making things harder for another developer down the line.

If you want to make changes to a site, get full access and do things properly.

Comment: They not give us so I need to do it maybe with !important even that's not working well...

Comment: @Hanan Sounds like your are hacking some other project… ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if is really true that the CSS from the bottom works, then if you want to override a rule that has been created before yours you have to use the important modificator.

Just google a bit about "css important". For example:

```
.button {
   color: white               !important;
}

.button {
   color: red;
}
```

Will keep the white value. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Please don't use `!important` if it's not really necessary. See the link in my answer above. Normally you just need to re-define the rules for some selector. In some cases you'll need to use an extended selector. For example, to style an elements property via a class, which was already styled via an id. In that case just prepend the class by the id.

Comment: I guess !important is useful when you have no other option. If you can not place your rules after the rules you want to rewrite.